# How do I check for user input when using the VBA IsEmpty function in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a checkbox that changes the color of a cell if it is checked. The user can't print the page until a value is entered into the highlighted field. Both the checkbox and restrict printing modules are working properly.

How do I change the color of the highlighted field once the user enters a value? I wrote the below code, but it only works when I manually run it. I am newer to VBA so any help is appreciated!

```
Private Sub Can_Print()
    If IsEmpty(Range("G54")) = False Then
        MsgBox "You may now print."
        Range("G54").Interior.Color = RGB(221, 235, 247)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Take a look at the [`Worksheet_Change`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Worksheet.Change) event.

Comment: You can also do this with a  conditional formatting formula

Comment: @Comintern Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code under the worksheet you want it run for:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Value <> "" Then
        MsgBox "You may now print"
        Target.Interior.Color = RGB(221, 235, 247)
    End If
End Sub
```

if you don't want it to work for any cell then just replace target with the range you want.

Comment: You should use the Intersect() function to ensure the correct cell is being colored

Comment: @VBA_SQL_Programmer Thanks for the assist!

Comment: You could also add Trim and use Len, as in `If Not Len(Trim(Target.Value)) = 0 `

Answer (score 0):

In case you haven't got it yet, please check this . You need to copy your code onto the worksheet events. You need to attach your code to the worksheet change event.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    Set KeyCells = Range("G5:G6")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then

        Application.EnableEvents = False
            If IsEmpty(Target) = False Then
                'MsgBox "You may now print."
                Target.Interior.Color = RGB(22, 235, 247)
            Else
                Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
            End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If
End Sub
```